# In App Billing crashed in API 23

Tags: android

I am Upgrading my project to API 23. My App is crashed on In-App Billing with API 23 but its works on API 22. When purchasehandler calls the PurchaseItem method, the app is crash on launchPurchaseFlow method.

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-26 13:24:12.048 3031-3031/com.example.--- E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.---, PID: 3031
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: launchPurchaseFlow
        at com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.checkSetupDone(IabHelper.java:790)
        at com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:380)
        at com.MyQalam.InappPurchase.InappPurchaseHandler.PurchaseItem(InappPurchaseHandler.java:31)
        at com.MyQalam.ShalatIndonesian.IndexActivity.onMenuItemSelected(IndexActivity.java:95)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1151)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:468)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:129)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my Code:

```java
private Context mContext;
private IabHelper billinHelper;
public InappPurchaseHandler(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        billinHelper = new IabHelper(context, AppPropertyKey.BASE_64_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"IABHEPLER",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

public void setonsetupCompleteListener(IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener listener){
        billinHelper.startSetup(listener);
    }


public void OnItemInventoryAsyn(IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener){

        billinHelper.queryInventoryAsync(listener);
    }
public void PurchaseItem(String sku,IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener){
        //if(billinHelper.isSetupDone() && !billinHelper.isAsyncInProgress())//change
        if (billinHelper!=null)
        billinHelper.launchPurchaseFlow((Activity) mContext, sku, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS, 123, listener, "");
    }


public void OnBillingActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        billinHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
public void disposeBillingHelper() {
            if (billinHelper != null) {
                billinHelper.dispose();
            }
            billinHelper = null;
        }
```

Here is the code where i call the function:

```java
purchaseHandler.PurchaseItem(RemoveAds.SKU,
                    new OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                                          Purchase info) {
                            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                                dataManager.setRemoveAds(true);
                                Toast.makeText(IndexActivity.this,
                                        "Ads Successfully Removed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                RefrshActivity();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the solution man:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            purchaseHandler.OnBillingActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was testing In-App Billing on an emulator which cause the crash. In-App Billing wont test on the emulator it can be tested by :

1. Your Real Android Device with sign apk.
2. Another one is your Android Developer Account which upload your sign apk then test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out more details about Testing In-app Billing from https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html. This would help solving the issue.